# Put projected Angular content into a component through routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, projection

In a context of a micro-front-end application I have a projected content in the `app.module.ts` that I want to put in a component that was instantiated via the router.

Here is a solution that does not work:

1. I referenced the projected content as follow

```html
  <ng-template #projected>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

2. I set the reference in a service

```js
@ViewChild('projected', { static: true }) templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>;
// ...
this.service.projectedRef = templateRef;
```

3. use it in the component that was created by the router

```html
 <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="service.projectedRef"></ng-container>
```

Any idea why doesn't that work and how I can solve this problem?

Note: when I use `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="service.projectedRef"></ng-container>` inside the app.component.html, it works fine, but not inside the routed component.

Comment: What error do you get in F12 console?

Comment: None actually, it just doesn't render anything